# How can i await for file to upload so i can upload next image with params

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, file-upload, async-await

I am using Drag and Drop file to upload multiple images.

[ngx-file-drop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-file-drop)

How to use with async await to upload images because i want to send params to next image returned from 1st request.

`post_id` returned from 1st request should be sent with all next images.

this is what is am doing but it is not waiting:

```
dropped(files: NgxFileDropEntry[]) {
    this.files = files;
    for (const droppedFile of files) {

      // Is it a file?
      if (droppedFile.fileEntry.isFile) {
        const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
        fileEntry.file(async (file: File) => {
          // Here you can access the real file
          console.log(droppedFile.relativePath, file);

          await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.uploadImages(file, 'UploadImage', this.postId).subscribe((res: any) => {
              if (res.status == true) {
                resolve(true);
                this.postId = res.data.post_id; // i want to send this ID in next request. 
              } else {
                reject();
                console.log(res.message);
              }
            })
          });


        });
      } else {
        // It was a directory (empty directories are added, otherwise only files)
        const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemDirectoryEntry;
        console.log(droppedFile.relativePath, fileEntry);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: you're starting all promises in the same time, try to run it with the debugger or put console logs to check what is happening. You may try to extract first call outside of the loop and then pass the id to the rest of the calls in the loop.

Comment: with debugger it is working as expected. and all next calls sent with id. but without debugger is not working

Answer (score 0):

[You can use this trait:

```
public paramsArray = [
  {
    param1: '1',
    param2:  2
  },
  {
    param1: '3',
    param2:  4
  }
]

public subject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<null>;

construnctor() {
  this.subject.asObservable().subscribe((value) => {
    if (value) {
      this.http.uploadImage(value).subscribe((res) => {
        if (this.paramsArray.length) {
          this.subject.next(paramsArray.splice(0, 1)[0]);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

startUploading() {
  this.subject.next(this.paramsArray.splice(0, 1)[0]);
}
```

It will start from index 0 of paramsArray and uploads them one after another.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that for the first photo that is going to be uploaded, you have a `postId` stored in `this.postId` variable. We'll be using that one to upload the first photo, and then introduce a second variable to hold the `post_id` returned by the upload method.

We're using `Observable` instead of `Promise` because as we all know, promises are going to be executed no matter what in the moment we instantiate them, which is not what we want. We're also using [`concat`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concat) to make sure all the files are going to be uploaded one by one.

```
private photoPostId: number | null = null;

dropped(files: NgxFileDropEntry[]) {
  this.files = files;

  const tasks = files.map((droppedFile) => {
    return new Observable<number>((subscriber) => {
      if (droppedFile.fileEntry.isFile) {
        const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
        fileEntry.file(async (file: File) => {
          // Here you can access the real file
          console.log(droppedFile.relativePath, file);

          this.http
            .uploadImages(
              file,
              'UploadImage',
              this.photoPostId ?? this.postId
            )
            .subscribe((res: any) => {
              if (res.status == true) {
                subscriber.next(res.data.post_id); // i want to send this ID in next request.
              }
            });
        });
      } else {
        // It was a directory (empty directories are added, otherwise only files)
        const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemDirectoryEntry;
        console.log(droppedFile.relativePath, fileEntry);
      }
      subscriber.complete();
    });
  });

  concat(...tasks).subscribe((postId) => {
    this.photoPostId = postId;
  });
}
```

Comment: First time `this.postId` is empty string `''` because server generates that Id against first Image and in all next images i sent back that postId.

Comment: i also have tried this with `Observables` but same result.

Comment: Did you try the solution I posted? How is this working for you?

Comment: nope. it not working. again it is not waiting for previous request to get complete.

Comment: The requests are done sequentially, that's what `concat` does. Did you try to replace the contents of your method with what is in this answer?

Comment: Yes, i did try you answer but its not working. I observe that the requests are in sequence but the post id is not getting updated.

Comment: Debug it (at least console.logs), see what happens in the subscribe handler, you should get the post id there.

Comment: ok let me try again

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for a solution on how to get the file using Ngx-file-drop, this is the solution that worked for me.

Pseudocode

- Get the `droppedItems`
- Filter for files
- Create an obervable stream
- fetch the file(s) and perform desired action

Code

```
dropped(files: NgxFileDropEntry[]) {
    const droppedFileList = files.filter((droppedFile) => droppedFile.fileEntry.isFile);

    const subscription = new Subscription();

    subscription.add(
      from([droppedFileList])
        .pipe(
          switchMap((array) => {
            console.log('array', array);
            const result = array?.map((droppedFile) => {
              const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
              const promise = new Promise((res) => {
                fileEntry.file((file) => res(file));
              })
              return from(promise);
            })

            return forkJoin(result);            
         })
        )
        .subscribe({
          next: (fileList) => console.log('fileList',fileList),
          error:(err)=> console.error(err)
          complete: () => subscription.unsubscribe()
        });
}

**For API calls**

dropped(files: NgxFileDropEntry[]) {
    const droppedFileList = files.filter((droppedFile) => droppedFile.fileEntry.isFile);

    const subscription = new Subscription();

    subscription.add(
      from([droppedFileList])
        .pipe(
          switchMap((array) => {
            console.log('array', array);
            const result = array?.map((droppedFile) => {
              const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
              const promise = new Promise((res) => {
                fileEntry.file((file) => res(file));
              })
              return from(promise);
            })

            return forkJoin(result);            
         }),
         switchMap((fileList) => apiFn(fileList))
        )
        .subscribe({
          next: (resp) => console.log('resp',resp),
          error:(err)=> console.error(err)
          complete: () => subscription.unsubscribe()
        });
}

apiFn(result){
  const calls = result.map(file => apiServiceFn(file));
  return forkJoin([...calls]);
}
```

You can know more about ForkJoin here - https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin

Here is a Stackblitz app that can serve as a basis https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-osb6kk?file=src/app/app.component.ts